# RPM running to high and don't kick down on 2005 trailblazer

Tags: transmission, rpm

My 2005 trailblazer automatic ! had a almost new engine put in April. Ran perfect. It started pour oil and my rpm would not kick down without me letting off gas. Both started at the same time ! Oil issue ended up being a bad oil sending sensor. But now RPM are still high. I can give it light steady gas and it will kick down and go till about 3 rpm. then it shoots way over 6 till i let off gas. I can slowly give gas again and it goes but rpm never goes under 3 or 4 while giving gas. Other than that it runs  fine. I have no engine light so computer don't read anything ! I'm lost. It's like driving a standard and not properly shifting

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you state "never goes under 3 or 4" rpm, are you saying *3 to 4 **thousand*** rpm? Could you better describe the oil problem? Did both of these start happening at the same time? Is the check engine light on? If so, what codes are showing because of it?

Comment: " ! had a almost new engine put in April" we need more info on exactly what was replaced, if it is a used engine was it the same year model and vehicle it came from?